# What can I do to speed up my load test using NBomber? (VS LT 250 RPS easily; NBomber maxed with 25 RPS)

Tags: .net-core, performance-testing, load-testing

We've been using Visual Studio Load Test to exercise our .NET Framework 4.7.2 telemetry client where we can set up the load test to post metrics to our Rabbit MQ at a rate of about 250 metrics per second. Recently, we've had to migrate our telemetry client to .NET Core and need to run load testing and verify that it can still post metrics at the same rate.  Now, Visual Studio Load Test (VSLT) is being deprecated and has no support for .NET Core framework so we've had to look to something like NBomber to use in place of VSLT.

With regards to NBomber, there doesn't seem to be enough documentation or support that I can get because I've tried all I know and cannot get NBomber to post more than 25 metrics per second. At the same time, I'm seeing 100% CPU usage.

Anyone has any insight to share with me?  Thanks in advance for your help,
Tien

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, my logic was bad.  A senior developer and friend shared with me some insights where I was initializing a telemetry client for each posting of a metric.  This was the key to high consumption of CPU and not allowing me to reach the performance I was expecting.  I'm in the process of re-coding my test(s) so that NBomber can be used to initialize 250 telemetry clients posting a minimum of 1MM metrics within an hour.  I ran a fix yesterday that posted 17K metrics within 56secs with just 1 telemetry client or of about a rate of 300 RPS.  I thought VS LT was awesome, but I'm thinking NBomber is quite impressive.

Cheers to Load Testing with NBomber!!
Tien

Answer (score 0):

If single instance of NBomber is consuming 100% of CPU and not conducting the necessary load you will need to set up another machine and run NBomber in [distributed cluster mode](https://nbomber.com/docs/cluster-overview)

> **Why do you need cluster?**

> - **You reached the point that the capacity of one node is not enough to create a relevant load.**

> - You want to delegate running multiple scenarios to different nodes. For example, you want to test the database by sending in parallel read and write queries. In this case, one node can send inserts and another one can send read queries.

> - You want to simulate a real production load that requires several nodes to participate. For example, you may have one node that periodically writes data to the Kafka broker and two nodes that constantly read this data from the Redis cache.

Also it seems that [Microsoft recommends using Apache JMeter™](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/microsoft-recommends-jmeter-and-blazemeter-as-preferred-load-testing-tools) so it might worth giving it a try. JMeter is capable of sending messages to various MQ implementations and its documentation is more concise, i.e. see [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)

Comment: Hello @Dmitri T
Thank you kindly for your inputs.  I've added an answer that solved my problem.  Not sure if this is the right way to do it but please forgive me if it's incorrect.  :-)  Thanks again for your help!